# MySQL: "order by" inside of "group by"

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a MySQL table of `names`, which consists of two fields: `name` and `rank`. The `name` value is not unique can have multiple matches.

The problem: I want to select records, grouped by `name`, but if there are more than one `name`, the one with the highest `rank` should be taken.

An example:

Tom 2

Ben 1

Ben 2

> SELECT * FROM `names` GROUP BY `name`
>   ORDER BY `rank` DESC

Usually returns:

Tom 2

Ben 1

I need:

Tom 2

Ben 2

Since there are two Bens, but the second one with a higher rank.

It seems, that MySQL grouping takes the first name and ignores the rest.

How do I order records inside "group by", so I could say which record should be taken, if there is more than one with the same `name`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need an [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) called `max`:

```
select name, max(rank)
  from names
 group by name;
```

This way you will retrieve all distinct names, each one associated with its max rank.

Comment: You still have to use `group by name` so that the `max(rank)` per `name` is returned, and not the overall `max(rank)`.

Comment: @Dennis: yes. already added that part. forgot with the rush to get the question to be the first one. :-)

Comment: This gives the rows where every name has the max rank, what you only wanted the name that had the max rank?

Answer (score 7):

For me it has been worked:

To take the last row inside a group:

```
select * from 
( select name, rank from names order by rank desc ) as a 
group by name
```

Comment: The syntax isn't correct(you can't `select *` whereas `group by name`)

Comment: I suppose that you didn't try to do this, because, if you had tried, you would known that it works. Not only on this example, but you can also get all information in the max row line.

Comment: +1 You are right, I didn't know that `mysql` supports such a syntax. `MSSQL` and `Oracle` don't...

Answer (score 4):

Use `max()`:

```
select name,
       max(rank)
from names
group by name
order by max(rank) desc
```